# Setting up a connection in Rstudio to a Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, rstudio

Below is my code to connect to a Oracle database

`connection <- DBI::dbConnect(jdbcDriver,"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//aaaaa1111.bb.com:PORT_NUM/SID",user = 'user', password = 'password')`

and i got this error 
rror in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: the /SID part - what you supplied there, the server is saying, we don't know about this database that you are trying to connect to

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I got the SID by right clicking the database in SQL developer and copy and paste the SID

Comment: Then I would make sure you're connecting to the right server